# UAT and Production environment can use the same server?

Tags: solution-package, solution-deployment, custom-solution

I have custom SharePoint solution. I want to create UAT and Production environment on the same server. Is it possible to deploy the solution on a single server?

**Scenario** - I have one custom SharePoint solution called Demo.
Now I want to deploy this solution two different environments like UAT and Production on 2 different web application. How can I achieve this?

On one application (UAT environment) there is a different version of the solution and on another web application (Production environment)  there is a different version of the solution.

**FYI** - I have just one solution and want to create UAT and Production environment on a different web application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**As a short answer:** No  You can't add two different versions of the same solution name in the same environment.

---

**Workarounds**

You have 2 workarounds

1. Redploy the same solution with a different name.
2. In UAT and Production farms, Try to do the following:

   - Back up the current solution  as mentioned [here](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp-solution-package/).
   - Retract and remove the old version using PowerShell.
   - Redeploy it again with the new package using PowerShell.

---

**To retract solution using PowerShell**

```
Uninstall-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp
```

**To delete it from the farm**

```
Remove-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp
```

**To Add the new package**

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "C:\Solution\qassas.wsp"
```

**To Install the WSP to a specific web application**

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity <solution.wsp> -WebApplication <Site URL> -GacDeployment
```

For more details check [Install and deploy SharePoint Solution Package (WSP) Using PowerShell](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp-solution-package/)